# Why does conda package install complain about both python abi 3.7 and 3.9?

Tags: python, installation, package, conda, mamba

I'm trying to install a package in a conda environment (python=3.9), and I get the following error:

```
Encountered problems while solving:

nothing provides python_abi 3.7.* *_cp37m needed by [package]
```

I then tried installing python_abi=3.7 just to see if it worked (though I suspected this wasn't the fundamental way to solve this issue).

```
mamba install -c conda-forge python_abi=3.7
```

This gave the error message:

```
Encountered problems while solving: package python_abi-3.7-0_cp37m requires python 3.7.*, but none of the providers can be installed
```

Using conda to try to install the same way gave a different error message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.17
```

It was unclear if this was an issue with the python version of the environment, so I tried creating another environment with python version 3.7 and installing the same package, but got the following error again (Package1 being another dependency for the original package I am trying to install) :

```
Encountered problems while solving:

nothing provides python_abi 3.9.* *_cp39 needed by [package1]
```

How can I fix this to finish installing?

Comment: Rather than predefining the Python version, please try creating a new environment defining "`package1`" as the only constraint. What Python version does it resolve? `mamba create -n foo package1`.

Comment: @merv Thank you for the suggestion, creating a new environment defining package1 didn't work (same error) but creating one for [package] without predefining the Python version worked and now everything seems to be installed successfully.